# Azure Storage - how to restore a directory by Node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure-storage

I know [Point-in-time restore for block blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/point-in-time-restore-overview) could restore all blobs in the given directory. I wonder there is a way to use "Point-in-time restore" by Node.js or other languages?

For example, if my customers want to restore their data and I provide a web page(API) to them, they could do that by themself.

Updated:

I found [BlobRestoreParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/arm-storage/blobrestoreparameters?view=azure-node-latest)

Answer (score 1):

The article you refer to mentions the `Restore Blob Ranges` operation to initiate a restore.

> To initiate a point-in-time restore, call the [Restore Blob Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/restoreblobranges) operation and specify a restore point in UTC time. You can specify lexicographical ranges of container and blob names to restore, or omit the range to restore all containers in the storage account. Up to 10 lexicographical ranges are supported per restore operation.

Following that link brings you to the documentation for the operation, which is a REST API that you can call.

##### Sample request

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storage-account}/restoreBlobRanges?api-version=2021-04-01
```

##### Sample body

```
{
  "timeToRestore": "2021-09-11T12:00:00.0000000Z",
  "blobRanges": [
    {
      "startRange": "container/{blobpath1}",
      "endRange": "container/{blobpath2}"
    },
    {
      "startRange": "container2/{blobpath3}",
      "endRange": ""
    }
  ]
}
```